# SELECT fields where there no exist others in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, anti-join

I have the following table schema:

```
Table 1
-
field1
Table 2
-
field1 | field2
```

What I want to do is select **field2 from the second table** where **field1** in the second table doesn't exist in the first table (**field1**).

I had this :

```
SELECT t2.field2
     , t2.field1
FROM table1 t1
   , table2 t2
WHERE t2.field1 != t1.field1
```

The problem is that this query will retrieve multiple repeated information from table2 if multiple rows apply in table1. I added `DISTINCT` and/or `LIMIT` but it still doesn't work. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT t2.field2, t2.field1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.field1 NOT IN (SELECT t1.field1 FROM table1 t1);
```

This will give you all rows from `table2` that have a `field1` which is not in `table1`.

You can now use `DISTINCT` or `LIMIT` on the outermost query for any further processing.

Comment: how does this differentiate from NOT EXISTS?

Comment: @AndreCalenta: as I said, you can now use `DISTINCT` if you don't want duplicate identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` together with `IS NULL` check :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.field2
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
WHERE t1.field1 IS NULL
```

Comment: @GolezTrol : using `LEFT JOIN` appears to be a basic anti-join solution and the above one should be even [faster](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) than yours (_for MySQL RDBMS_).

Comment: I was reading that too. I don't know if it still applies though (the text is from 2009). But anyway, you've addressed my other remarks, so now this solution is at least a valid query too. And indeed possibly faster.

Comment: @GolezTrol : Well, thank you for pointing out about the `DISTINCT` part – I've started answering after I've read the first part.)

Comment: By the way, that link is about `not nullable columns`. If the columns are nullable, you will need a slightly different query for joins and `not in`. The syntax for `not exists` remains the same (which is a big plus, I think) and it [performs better](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/) in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The title of your question is almost the command you need: 'NOT EXIST'. SQL is so simple. ;)

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.field2 
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE t1.field1 = t2.field1)
```

Comment: how does this differentiate from NOT IN?

Comment: You can use `DISTINCT` now. It should work if you only select the field that you need.

Comment: Not because of that... table 1 has multiple rows where it might not exist, so it returns multiple rows...

Comment: I reverted the table names. They now seem to match your question a bit better. ;)

Comment: When compared to `not in`, this solution will still work if Table1.field1 is nullable and contains `null`s. I think `not in` will fail in that case. On the other hand, `not in` [used to be slightly faster](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/), although I don't know if that is still the case, and it might depend on [the exact use case](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html).